# Windows 10 Jenkins slave keeps rebooting and Jenkins won't start and Edge won't open

Tags: jenkins, windows-10, microsoft-edge

We have a vm windows 10 machine jenkins slave that keeps rebooting although we have turned off windows auto update. When it restarts it tries to restart Jenkins which throws this error:

```
 >  java.lang.exception the server rejected the connection: none of the protocols were accepted at 
 > hudson.remoting.engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:286)
 > at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:262)
```

We then have to go in and manually start jenkins agent. This is not good for our automated tests that require this machine.

As an additional side note: Edge won't open. You can click on it all day and nothing appears to occur.
Any ideas on what is causing the windows reboot and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wound up having our lab team create a new vm and deleting this one.

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like a cause of malware, try downloading a free anti virus {have some help with this, alot contain malwate}.

Best Regards
Shadow
Thanks!

additional notes! Ive had this problem many times with windows 8 in a virtual box!

Comment: I ment malware. dont judge me I like being funny